# Where did the idea for "Coraline" come from?

Tags: coraline

Where did the idea for the movie *Coraline* come from? I'm not looking for specifics. Just a general statement, such as, "It cam from a dream about dolls the author had."

Answer (score 9):

According to the author of the book, Neil Gaiman:

> GAIMAN: The inspiration for Coraline was that it was a story for my daughters, with a girl who got to be brave but was normal. She’s a bit Holly, a bit me, but mostly herself.

This comes from a short interview on [Flames Rising](http://www.flamesrising.com/neil-gaiman-on-coraline/)

It'd also be worth watching this interview on [Nerdist](http://nerdist.com/neil-gaiman-shares-his-inspiration-behind-coraline-exclusive/).